# Returning pair of indexes based on a condition in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns, col1 = "Name" and col2 = "university". There are more than 1000 observations. What I would like is to get a list of the indexes (connected to the names) where the two person attended the same university.

For example, the names in order are Adam (University of Cambrdige), Eva (University of Cambrdige), Bran (University of Oxford), Mike (University of Oxford), Lily (University of Stanford).

The output should be a list [[0,1], [2,3]]. Obviously, I want to avoid duplicats like [1,0] and [3,2].

Comment: why taking `[2,3]` for different universities?

Comment: Mistake on my part, edited the question. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

out = (df.reset_index().groupby('University')['index']
         .agg(lambda g: list(combinations(g, 2)))
       )
```

Output:

```
University
University of Cambrdige    [(0, 1)]
University of Oxford       [(2, 3)]
University of Stanford           []
Name: index, dtype: object
```

Or as a flat list:

```
out = [pair for _, g in df.reset_index().groupby('University')['index']
       for pair in combinations(g, 2)]
```

Output: `[(0, 1), (2, 3)]`

Used input:

```
   Name               University
0  Adam  University of Cambrdige
1   Eva  University of Cambrdige
2  Bran     University of Oxford
3  Mike     University of Oxford
4  Lily   University of Stanford
```